# IFTTT - retweet if hashtag

Tags: ifttt

I am trying to create an IFTTT recipe which should make a retweet from an account if any tweet from someone has a specific hashtag in it.If I try to create one myself like this:

[image]

It gives me an error:

> Twitter does not support use of this Trigger and Action combination

I was not able to find any suitable recipe for it and the support won't answer.

Comment: I have tried to find a suitable recipe from one that is already existing but all of them only retweet from a specific user...no possibility to retweet once a specific hashtag appears. I also tried to create one myself but there again is the same problem with not beeing able to specify a hashtag which should be searched for and then reweeted. Also the support didn't really answer anything, they just sent me a link with FAQ's where I also couldn't find anything suitable for my problem.

Comment: Well, if you're looking for existing code (IFTTT or otherwise), this isn't the right place. This site is about programming, i.e. creating _new_ code. So if you tried to create a new recipe yourself, this is the right place, but you should put your attempt in the question above (there's an [edit] option at the bottom)

Comment: I just did my best in editing the question so it is fit for stackoverflow :)

Comment: TBH we quite dislike pictures of text; can you just put the code in the question? There's a `[ code ]` button in the edit mode.

Comment: I am sorry. I am not very familiar with posting questions on stackoverflow yet but I can not get any code from an IFTTT recipe or I just don't know how to do so exactly. Would be very grateful if someone could tell me how to do that.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to copy a recipe either. Guess we have to wait for someone with IFTTT experience to pop up.

Comment: Try asking at the http://superuser.com part of Stack Exchange for these types of questions, unless you have your own code Stack Overflow is not the right place to post.

Comment: I guess you need to work around the error with a recipe like: "IF <twitter> then <maker web-hook>" - Maker web-hook channel/service requires you to write your own server application. The server-app needs to expose a web-service which will be hit by IFTTT with the tweet and then your server will then make a request to twitter.com.